# wildfly+intelij Error running admin process

Tags: intellij-idea, wildfly

Im using wildfly-8.2.0.Final. It works fine on work pc. But when I try deploy it on home pc I get this error

`Error running admin process:`
`Message: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/wildfly/security/password/Password Stack trace: com.intellij.javaee.process.common.JavaeeProcessUtilException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/wildfly/security/password/Password at com.intellij.javaee.process.common.MethodInvocator.invoke(MethodInvocator.java:47) at com.intellij.javaee.oss.process.JavaeeProcess.processRequest(JavaeeProcess.java:112) at com.intellij.javaee.oss.process.JavaeeProcess.run(JavaeeProcess.java:52) at com.intellij.javaee.oss.process.JavaeeProcess.main(JavaeeProcess.java:31) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:66) Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/wildfly/security/password/Password at com.intellij.javaee.oss.jboss.agent.WildFly11Agent.createAuthHandler(WildFly11Agent.java:15) at com.intellij.javaee.oss.jboss.agent.JBoss7Agent.doConnect(JBoss7Agent.java:49) at com.intellij.javaee.oss.agent.SimpleAgentBase$1.doJob(SimpleAgentBase.java:24) at com.intellij.javaee.oss.agent.SimpleAgentBase$1.doJob(SimpleAgentBase.java:20) at com.intellij.javaee.oss.agent.SimpleAgentJob.perform(SimpleAgentJob.java:12) at com.intellij.javaee.oss.agent.SimpleAgentBase.connect(SimpleAgentBase.java:33) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at com.intellij.javaee.process.common.MethodInvocator.invoke(MethodInvocator.java:41) ... 8 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wildfly.security.password.Password at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ... 19 more 19:06:24,746 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ehospital]`

I am using:

Intelij Idea,
wildfly-8.2.0.Final,
jdk1.8.0_231

Has anyone faced this error?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with Postgre version and driver. Downloaded version for my Postgre and
changed driver in JBOSS_HOME\modules\org\postgres\main. That helped me